# signal handler in a thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

I am writing a multithreaded program and i have this question:
Suppose that, while executing in the main thread, i want to terminate all
child-threads. I can't just send them a termination signal cause i want them
to free dynamically allocated memory first. Can i define a specific signal handler
function in each thread function that is executed, which in turn is going to call
a cleanup function that i will write to do so? If not how can i accomplish my goal??

Thanks,
Nikos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the man page for [`pthread_cancel`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html):

> When a cancellation requested is acted on, the following steps occur for
>    thread (in this order):

```
   1. Cancellation clean-up handlers are popped (in the reverse of the order in
      which they were pushed) and called.  (See pthread_cleanup_push(3).)

   2. Thread-specific data destructors are called, in an unspecified order.  (See
      pthread_key_create(3).)

   3. The thread is terminated.  (See pthread_exit(3).)
```

So you can use `pthread_cancel` from your main, provided you have registered you cleanup handlers correctly using the above functions.

(Do read that man page completely though, it has a lot of important information.)

**Edit**: (from comments) If you plan on using `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` and need to insert a cancellation point somewhere in your code, then use [`pthread_testcancel`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_testcancel.3.html). This function checks if a cancellation was requested. If that is the case, the cancellation is serviced (i.e. that call never returns). Otherwise it has no effect.

Comment: This is a good solution. I have used it myself and the design comes out neat.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I am thinking of using pthread_cleanup_push with an appropriate exit handler function to free everything. If i set PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED is it valid to have a sleep(0) as a cancellation point so i won't have any overhead?

Comment: @nikos: that's not the best way. use [`pthread_testcancel`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_testcancel.3.html), that's exactly what it's for. `sleep` can be implemented with signals, and  `sleep(0)` is not guaranteed not to sleep - the only guarantee is that it will sleep _at least_ 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust strategy requires cooperation from the child threads: you set a flag that the threads periodically check and, when the flag is set, free whatever resources they're using and then terminate.

Comment: `periodically check a variable` of course being shorthand for `use a pthread condition variable` -- **`<whistle/>`**

Comment: This is not possible if the thread might be blocked long-term or permanently on a blocking/sleeping syscall. That's why cancellation exists.

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation (Mat's answer) is the correct and canonical one, but if you want a different approach, you can install a no-op signal handler using `sigaction` without the `SA_RESTART` flag and use `pthread_kill` with whatever signal number you chose in order to interrupt (`EINTR`) whatever the thread might have been blocked on. Combined with this, aix's answer works.